# Validate an array of array

Tags: javascript, arrays

It is possible to validate an array like this:

```
const Array = [[1, 2], ['hello', 'hi'], []]
```

I need to kwon when one array is empty or is ".length === 0" but only if one of the array is empty it say an error and if all are empty is the same error.

for example this is an error

```
const Array = [[1, 2], ['hello', 'hi'], []]
const Array = [[1, 2], [], []]
const Array = [[], ['hello', 'hi'], []]
```

when all array has values then do something else like show an alert

Comment: [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) or the version for the negation, [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every), are your friends.

Comment: You cannot redeclare a `const`, which shouldn't be `Array` anyways, since `Array` is a predefined constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

```js
const myArray = [[1, 2], ['hello', 'hi'], []];

if (myArray.find((innerArray) => innerArray.length === 0)) {
  console.log("Some error")
} else {
  console.log("Do something else");
}
```

Comment: beautiful code, thanks for the `innerArray` [+1]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function to check if one or more items of an Array matches a certain condition. Here is what it would look like applied to your specific case:

```js
const array_of_arrays = [[1, 2], ['hello', 'hi'], []]

let contains_empty_arrays = array_of_arrays.some((sub_array) => sub_array.length === 0)

console.log(contains_empty_arrays )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Array.prototype.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```js
const data = [[], ["hello", "hi"], []],
  check = data.every(item => item.length);
if (!check) {
  alert("Empty Values");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try running the snippet below:

```js
const myArray = [[1, 2], ['hello', 'hi'], []];

var with_empty = false;

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {

  if(myArray[i].length == 0){
    with_empty = true;
    break;
  }

}

if(with_empty)
  alert('There is an empty value!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to do something like:

```js
function fullNest(arrayOfArrays){
  for(let a of arrayOfArrays){
    if(!a.length){
       return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
}
const nest = [[1, 2], ['hello', 'hi'], []];
console.log(nest); console.log(fullNest(nest)); console.log('-'.repeat(50)); 
nest[2].push('full now'); console.log(nest); console.log(fullNest(nest));
```